# Convert double to mysql date format

Tags: mysql, datetime, epoch

In mysql,    I had one table students and that table contains one column name as runtime and that contains values like `1381387683741`, `1381387683739` etc.

when I convert this using [covertor](http://www.epochconverter.com/)
it shows results

> Thu, 10 Oct 2013 06:48:03 GMT

So my question is how I can convert this same as using mysql query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select from_unixtime(substring(runtime,1,10)) from students;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [from_unixtime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
SELECT
  from_unixtime(timestamp) 
FROM 
  your_table
```

Comment: column runtime data type is double when I run this query SELECT from_unixtime(runtime) FROM students;
 It shows results NULL